# how to set document height to the iframe can anyone suggest?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using an iframe in my application, where I am  trying to display a pdf in that iframe.
If i open the application on Ipad pdf is not scrolling. so i got a thought that if i apply a total pdf height to the iframe and putting in a div and trying to apply the overflow to that div but my problem is how to get the height of  document which is in iframe.

```
    <div>
         <iframe id="miscLinkFrame" src="holiday.pdf" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="500" width="760" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in simple way its not possible

**may be this logic work** but not sure
1st capture document's size with jscript which is called in  
2nd then change iframe size with/from jscript which is captured before (in 1st step)

try it may be this work

regard

Comment: i am not able to capture the document size because there is an javascript error like "Permission denied to access property ‘document’". this is because the domain is different from parent to iframe

Comment: in this case you can upload docs in your server and run it again, other ways i think we can't cross the other servere's security

Comment: yes exactly i uploaded into my server location but it is showing the same error again

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code :

```
$('#iframeid')[0].height="600px";
```

for reference please see [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sgbangale/Nn3EJ/)

Comment: my pdf file is dynamically changes i cannot put fixed height.